# "az network vnet peering create" results in "BadRequestError: Cannot parse the request."

Tags: azure, vnet

I am trying to peer two Azure vnets with CLI, therefor I followed the tutorial [Connect virtual networks with virtual network peering using the Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/tutorial-connect-virtual-networks-cli).
But the result is always "BadRequestError: Cannot parse the request"

```
# Get the id for myVirtualNetwork1.
vNet1Id=$(az network vnet show \
   --resource-group myResourceGroup \
   --name myVirtualNetwork1 \
   --query id --out tsv)

# Get the id for myVirtualNetwork2.
vNet2Id=$(az network vnet show \
   --resource-group myResourceGroup \
   --name myVirtualNetwork2 \
   --query id \
   --out tsv)

az network vnet peering create \
   --name myVirtualNetwork1-myVirtualNetwork2 \
   --resource-group myResourceGroup \
   --vnet-name myVirtualNetwork1 \
   --remote-vnet $vNet2Id \
   --allow-vnet-access
```

**--> BadRequestError: Cannot parse the request.**

Anyone any idea?

Comment: Hi, Do you still have any questions?  If the issue could solve by the reply, you could [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

The CLI commands work well on my side. I can reproduce the same error, please check if you have copied the sample exactly on your side.

For example, If you lack the `--out tsv` in the command, you will get the error.

[image]

### Update

It is something wrong or bug in the Azure CLI version `azure-CLI 2.16.0` because I can reproduce it with cloud shell or upgrade my local CLI version to `2.16.0` but the same commands work well on my local PowerShell or Bash with Azure CLI `2.11.1`.

[image]

On PowerShell

[image]

On WSL

[image]

In this case, you could [Install the specific version Azure CLI](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/13331) locally. Or you could have a look at the CLI bug report [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/16316).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the script I used in Azure CLI:

```
az group create --name myResourceGroup --location eastus
az network vnet create \
  --name myVirtualNetwork1 \
  --resource-group myResourceGroup \
  --address-prefixes 10.0.0.0/16 \
  --subnet-name Subnet1 \
  --subnet-prefix 10.0.0.0/24
az network vnet create \
  --name myVirtualNetwork2 \
  --resource-group myResourceGroup \
  --address-prefixes 10.1.0.0/16 \
  --subnet-name Subnet1 \
  --subnet-prefix 10.1.0.0/24
# Get the id for myVirtualNetwork1.
vNet1Id=$(az network vnet show \
  --resource-group myResourceGroup \
  --name myVirtualNetwork1 \
  --query id --out tsv)

# Get the id for myVirtualNetwork2.
vNet2Id=$(az network vnet show \
  --resource-group myResourceGroup \
  --name myVirtualNetwork2 \
  --query id \
  --out tsv)
az network vnet peering create \
  --name myVirtualNetwork1-myVirtualNetwork2 \
  --resource-group myResourceGroup \
  --vnet-name myVirtualNetwork1 \
  --remote-vnet $vNet2Id \
  --allow-vnet-access \
  --out tsv
```

[image]